# C#: linq return boolean instead of string

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select all the words from a list whose length is less or equal to 5. My current code only returns this:

1. true
2. false
3. false
4. true
5. true
6. true

I want the result to be the actual words.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] words = { "hello", "Welcome", "Rolling", "in", "The", "Deep" };
    var shortWords = from word in words select word.Length <= 5;

    foreach (var word in shortWords) {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you meant to do

```
var shortWords = from word in words where word.Length <= 5 select word;
```

or just

```
var shortWords = words.Where(word => word.Length <= 5);
```

Comment: It's worth marking this as the answer if it assisted you, so that people are not hesitant to answer your future questions.